# What is the setting in xprivacy to access the microphone?

Tags: security, audio, privacy, xposed-framework

I use xprivacy to set all permissions on my phone, but I accidently forbid the tuner app to access my microphone.

Which setting do I have to enable?

Comment: It may need to record audio: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />   or it may  need to just access the mic which is android.hardware.microphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out via xPrivacy itself:

I run the tuner app and after I saw in the privacy settings for the app, that it tried to access

"Medien (Audio,Fotos,Videos)" -> "**startRecording**" (one minute ago)

I allowed that and now it works ;)